# Getting XYZ and RBG (+time) data of custom 3D model

Tags: modeling, animation

I haven't used Blender before but as far as I know it's used for 3D modelling and animation. I'm currently working on a project that would create a hologram alike image/animation in real time using spinning RGB LED ball. I expect to have full coverage of a sphere (ball) with radius of 5cm. Total of 20 RGB LEDs will be used (possibly 28 depending on final design). There will be 2 strips of 10(14) LEDs placed diagonally (with 90 degrees angle between the strips). Hence, I'll need to have data for position, colour and time of the animation/image that I want to display.

So my question is, if I create an animation/image in Blender, would I be able to convert that model into XYZ, RGB and time data for all points (into a text file or any other readable file type)?
If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Export as OBJ files

Comment: @someonewithpc I think he means "for all points" of his custom volume, not all vertices of his model, so he would still have to sample that model at those points in space.

Comment: @PeterT Subdivide it?